# SQL Server - How to add a constraint when a Condition is met

Tags: sql-server

What I am trying to do is make it so a **Customer Order** cannot have the same **Product** specified multiple times in a **Order**. I think I need to check if the CustomerOderId is the same and if it is checked if they have more than one of the same ProductId but I am not sure how to go about it. I have the following tables in my DB

```
**OrderProduct**
(Id) int
(CustomerOrderId) int
(ProductId) int
(Quantity) int
(ProdcutRating) int

**CustomerOrder**
(Id) int
(CustomerId) int
(AddedDate) datetime

**Product**
(Id) int
(Name) nvarchar(75)
(Price) int
(AddedDate) datetime
```

I have tried the following but I think it would one; make it so no other customer could ever order the same product and two; would have to delete all current duplicates

```
ALTER TABLE OrderProduct ADD  CONSTRAINT [IX_UniqueProductId] UNIQUE 
NONCLUSTERED (ProductId ASC)
```

Anyone?

Comment: I'm sure there has to be more than this.. what if the customer wants to order the same product at a later time / date? Your constraints will have to be customer / product and order date time bound! would be so much easier if the front end does these checks before committing the records!

Comment: Yeah but its just one of the assignments I was given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly (and your data setup), all you would need to do is add the customerOrderId column to your unique index.  This would restrict you to having a product only once per customer order.

```
ALTER TABLE OrderProduct ADD  CONSTRAINT [IX_UniqueProductId] UNIQUE 
NONCLUSTERED (ProductId ASC, CustomerOrderID ASC)
```

This assumes that every time a customer orders an new Customer Order ID is generated and that the same customer could order the same product on subsequent orders.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thank you. Since there is already duplicates in the database how can i go about deleteing them

Comment: You can locate them with the following.  `Select CustomerOrderID, ProductId, count(*) from OrderProduct group by CustomerOrderID, ProductId  having count(*) > 1`   You'll have to take the list and find the OrderProduct IDs and decide which to delete

Comment: Thank you I have been working on this literally all day I can't believe how simple it was. Right now I am trying to do the delete statement and this is what I have `DELETE OrderProduct
Where ProductId = ProductId
AND CustomerOrderId = CustomerOrderId` But this just deletes everything because ever productid is equal to itself

Comment: Use the query i provided to locate the orders with multiple of the same product and then join that back to the OrderProduct table to get a full list of id,  you can then use a Rownumber (or other window function) to select one to delete.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you want only one product for each customerOrder in your OrderProduct. To achieve this you should use (productId, CustomerOrderId) as primary key of the OrderProduct table so there is a one to one relationship.

```
ALTER TABLE OrderProduct ADD  CONSTRAINT [IX_UniqueProductId] UNIQUE 
NONCLUSTERED (ProductId ASC, CustomerOrderID ASC)
```